# Uncaught (in promise) in vue-router when multiple clicks on a button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am working with vuejs and vue-router in Rails app. I have a button which calls a `nivagate` method. When user clicks on this `navigate` method, it hits an API enpoint via `axios` module and move to next component using `this.$router.push({name: "RouteName"})`. Problem is, when user clicks multiple on this button it gives `Uncaught (in promise) undefined` error in console. My guess is this error occurs because of vue-router. 
My question is, how can I catch or handle this error. I am using multiple such buttons in my app so I need a generic solution.

**Home.vue - component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button
      id="select_button"
      @click="onSelectClick"
    >
     Select
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    onSelectClick() {
      this.$`enter code here`axios.get('some-url').then(res => { 
        //print res on console
      }).catch(err => { 
        // print err on console
      })
      this.$router.push({ name: 'route-name' }); //route-name != home
    }
  }
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

**Error I get when I double(or more)-click on button**

```
Uncaught (in promise) undefined
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far. Also, since you have an error, please include the full error traceback in the text of the question.

Comment: @E.Zeytinci thank you for guidance. I have added simplified form of the code which is causing the issue. Hope it will help.

Comment: if this is vue CLI, I might suggest this: https://alligator.io/vuejs/lodash-throttle-debounce/

Comment: @MayraNavarro this is not a vue CLI. I am integrating vue in Rails app.

Comment: Perhaps you should only navigate to the next route if/when the API replies with no error ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV actually yes I can, but as i said I am using multiple button through-out my app in some button I am not hitting API and just routing to other component(s). In that case your suggestion won't be more useful, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error Cause:** vue-router causes this error when we call `this.$router.push({name: 'route-name'})` back to back multiple times without completing the previous call.

**Solution:** I can handle this error by adding a catch guard on router.push.

```
this.$router.push({name: 'router-name'}).catch(error => { //handle error here})
```

I made it generic by adding a method in vue mixin.

```
import router from '../router'
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    navigate(route) {
      router.push(route).catch(err => { //handle error here });
    }
  }
});
```

Now I can use this `navigate` method in my components like this.

```
<template>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      this.navigate({name: 'Home'})
    }
  }
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

`next({name: 'Login'})`

causes Uncaught (in promise)...

I replaced it with

```
router.push({name: 'Login'})
return
```

and no error!